# Detect Chrome browser in HTML

Tags: html, google-chrome

How can I detect the Google Chrome browser?
For example, I can detect Internet Explorer with this tag:

```
<!--[if lte IE]>
<link href="ie_only.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

I have one idea:

```
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
```

But maybe somebody has a better solution?

Update:
My page shows wrong only with Chrome browser, so i need load (only with chrome) special css file with updates

Comment: Take a step back - why are you trying to detect the *browser*?

Comment: You should detect that **feature** you are looking for rather than browser.

Comment: Are you looking for some specific feature related to html/html5 or css/css3? Try [mordenizr](http://www.modernizr.com/).

Comment: It could be a better idea to change the whole CSS. What is broken in Chrome? Does it work in Safari or other WebKit browser?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, you should be detecting **feature compatibility**, not browsers. That said, there are rare occasions when you need to target WebKit browsers in your CSS. For example,  I had a minor font size/rendering issue that only appeared in Chrome/Safari, and I fixed it with something like this:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  /* Chrome- and Safari-specific CSS here*/
}
```

Another warning: If something renders incorrectly in Chrome/Safari but not in Firefox, there's a good chance you have some other underlying issue, e.g. invalid markup. Be sure to validate your HTML and check for other problems before using the (slightly hackish) method above.

Comment: Its also coming for some windows IE browsers

Comment: Chrome, Opera and Edge reads this. Firefox not... my problem is with vh units in Chrome for scrolling... sorry but it doen't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
if (is_chrome) {
    document.write("Yaii it is Chrome only")
}
```

From: ["Simple way to detect chrome browser using javascript"](http://brianoryem.tumblr.com/post/6586001773/simple-way-to-detect-chrome-browser-using-javascript)

Comment: With the usual disclaimer that browser sniffing is in most cases a bad idea, this would be an ok answer.

Comment: also applies to opera 15+

Comment: Whilst I agree feature detection is better, I have a very odd case where a feature in Flash doesn't work in Chrome using the Pepper Flash doesn't work, so this appears to be the only solution I have.

Comment: @TomHart - I'd say no excuses required. Chrome is good, but certainly not a gold standard, and It doesn't take long to find exceptions where like any browser, a particular behavior is both unwelcome and unique. As long as you carefully comment what you did and why, there is nothing wrong with a so called 'hack' that makes all cases work as desired, eliminates a headache, and frees you for the next issue. Nothing says you can't revisit if/when a better solution is found.